# How does Feynman justify using this propagator expansion on the Dirac equation?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, dirac-equation, greens-functions

I'm slowly wading through Feynman's series of three papers from 1948-49 ([Space-Time Approach to Non-Rel QM](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/47756/1/FEYrmp48.pdf), [Theory of Positrons](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/3520/1/FEYpr49b.pdf), [Space-Time Approach to QED](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/3523/1/FEYpr49c.pdf)).  I think they're brilliant and they are certainly bringing me closer to understanding QFT, but I'm probably going to have multiple questions about them.

Now, I understood the derivation of the Schrodinger equation from the quantum action principle in the first paper.  And, although it took me a while because he omitted a couple steps, I got how he then decomposed the Schrodinger solution into a power series in the potential $U$ (2nd & 3rd pages of the Positrons paper - equations 6-9), which is the basis of Feynman diagrams.  As I comprehend it, if the Green's function from point $1$ to point $2$ is, loosely speaking,

$$K(2,1) = \sum_{\text{paths from 1 to 2}} e^{iS}$$

and $e^{iS}$ can itself be broken down as (using $T$ for kinetic energy and numerical indices for the elements of the path)

$$e^{i\int{T dt}}e^{i\int{-U dt}} \\
= e^{i\int{T dt}}e^{-iU_1 dt_1}e^{-iU_2 dt_2}e^{-iU_3 dt_3} \ldots \\
= e^{i\int{T dt}}(1 - iU_1dt_1\ldots)(1 - iU_2dt_2\ldots)(1 - iU_3dt_3\ldots) \ldots \\
= e^{i\int{T dt}}(1 - iU_1dt_1 - iU_2dt_2 - iU_3dt_3 - \ldots + U_1U_2dt_1dt_2 + \ldots)$$

then you just plug the whole thing back in for $e^{iS}$ in $K(2,1)$, and distribute the outer sum to each term inside the parentheses.  The first term (with just the 1) is then the free propagator $K_0$, while the first-order correction $K^{(1)}$ is all terms first order in $dt$, and so on.

So that's all good.  But the thing is, he then claims on the 4th page (equation 13) that essentially the same formula serves as the first-order correction to the free propagator for the *Dirac* equation:

$$K_+^{(1)}(2,1) = -i\int{K_+(2,3)\pmb{\textit{A}}(3) K_+(3,1)d\tau_3}$$

But how do we know the correction terms have the same form as for the Schrodinger equation?  For the latter, I can only assume their form was derived from the quantum action principle as above, since he didn't say.  But the Dirac equation itself does not result from that principle, right?